# User.Identity.GetUserId() return null on all my controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In all my controller, `User.Identity.GetUserId()` return null.

My User is an custom user, the definition is :

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IPrincipal
    {

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager,
            string authentificationType)
        {
            // Notez qu'authenticationType doit correspondre à l'élément défini dans CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authentificationType);
            // Ajouter les revendications personnalisées de l’utilisateur ici
            var nameIdentifierClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Id);
            userIdentity.AddClaim(nameIdentifierClaim);

            return userIdentity;
        }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

        public bool AccessEnabled { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Définition de l'identité de l'utilisateur
        /// </summary>
        public void DefineIdentity()
        {
            Identity = new GenericIdentity(Id);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why User.Identity.GetUserId() is always null :(

Thanks,

Charly

Comment: It would return null if you weren't actually logged in when this call is made

Comment: User is logged and User is not null. But GetUserId() return null.